# OnPaint event is not updating the form

Tags: winforms, paintevent

I know this code will work in Visual Studio 2010, but for some reason it is not updating the form in Visual Studio 2022. I alread tried DoubleBuffer and User styles... Any clue what is wrong with this code?

`

```
namespace Kaledoscópio
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        private readonly Random randomColor = new Random();

        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            tmrStep.Tick += TmrStep_Tick;
            tmrStep.Start();
        }

        private void TmrStep_Tick(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Invalidate();
        }

        private void frmMain_OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            Graphics g = e.Graphics;

            Color defaultColor = Color.FromArgb(randomColor.Next(255), randomColor.Next(255), randomColor.Next(255));
            using (Pen defaultPen = new Pen(defaultColor, 2))
            {
                int intHeight = this.ClientSize.Height;
                int intWidth = this.ClientSize.Width;

                int intMiddleHeight = intHeight / 2;
                int intMiddleWidth = intWidth / 2;

                Point posTopLeft = new Point(0, 0);
                Point posTopRight = new Point(intWidth, 0);
                Point posBottomLeft = new Point(0, intHeight);
                Point posBottomRight = new Point(intWidth, intHeight);
                Point posMiddle = new Point(intMiddleWidth, intMiddleHeight);
                Point posMiddleTop = new Point(intMiddleWidth, 0);
                Point posMiddleLeft = new Point(0, intMiddleHeight);
                Point posMiddleRight = new Point(intWidth, intMiddleHeight);
                Point posMiddleBottom = new Point(intMiddleWidth, intHeight);

                int defaultStep = randomColor.Next(3, 10);

                int b1;
                for (b1 = 0; b1 <= intMiddleWidth; b1 += defaultStep)
                {
                    g.DrawLine(defaultPen, posTopLeft.X + b1, posTopLeft.Y, posMiddle.X - b1, posMiddle.Y);
                    g.DrawLine(defaultPen, posTopRight.X - b1, posTopRight.Y, posMiddle.X + b1, posMiddle.Y);
                    g.DrawLine(defaultPen, posMiddle.X - b1, posMiddle.Y, posBottomLeft.X + b1, posBottomLeft.Y);
                    g.DrawLine(defaultPen, posMiddle.X + b1, posMiddle.Y, posBottomRight.X - b1, posBottomRight.Y);
                }

                int b2;
                for (b2 = 0; b2 <= intMiddleHeight; b2 += defaultStep)
                {
                    g.DrawLine(defaultPen, posMiddleTop.X, posMiddleTop.Y + b2, posMiddleLeft.X, posMiddleLeft.Y - b2);
                    g.DrawLine(defaultPen, posMiddleTop.X, posMiddleTop.Y + b2, posMiddleRight.X, posMiddleRight.Y - b2);
                    g.DrawLine(defaultPen, posMiddleRight.X, posMiddleRight.Y + b2, posMiddleBottom.X, posMiddleBottom.Y - b2);
                    g.DrawLine(defaultPen, posMiddleLeft.X, posMiddleLeft.Y + b2, posMiddleBottom.X, posMiddleBottom.Y - b2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Actually, it will works if I force a call to Paint() event inside OnPaint() event, but frankly, I don´t think this is the right way to deal with this... Paint() event should be called internally.

Comment: @Peter Duniho wrote and excelent answer that works perfctly. I really don´t get what´s the problem here.

Comment: Did you assigned the handler to the event?  `frmMain_OnPaint` is an event handler, so there should be a line of code like `this.Paint += frmMain_OnPaint;` in your constructor, or if you have assigned it through designer in InitializeComponents method. You can open the designer and select the form, then in the property browser, in events tab, choose the pain event and from dropdown choose `frmMain_OnPaint`. Or you can just assign the handler in constructor like what you did for the timer.

Comment: Alternatively, override `OnPaint` method, which is a virtual method of the base class and put the logic there.

Comment: What does *not updating the form* means? What is the interval of the Timer? Why didn't you override `OnPaint()`? Did you subscribe to the Paint event? -- The version of Visual Studio is irrelevant -- You *could* call `Invalidate()` inside the `OnPaint()` override or the `Paint` handler, but your Form (or any other Form, even if started with `ShowDialog()`) won't do much

Comment: base.OnPaint() is only valid when you override the OnPaint() method.  Right now it raises the Paint event over and over again without actually painting anything, should crash with this website's name.  Delete the call to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Base on your advices I found one solution.
No sure about any colletaral effect, but it works.

I just commented base.OnPaint(e) and it works.

Here is the final code:

```
namespace Kaledoscópio
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        private readonly Random randomColor = new Random();

        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            tmrStep.Tick += TmrStep_Tick;
            tmrStep.Start();
        }

        private void TmrStep_Tick(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Refresh();
        }

        private void frmMain_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            //base.OnPaint(e);

            Graphics g = e.Graphics;

            Color defaultColor = Color.FromArgb(randomColor.Next(255), randomColor.Next(255), randomColor.Next(255));
            using (Pen defaultPen = new Pen(defaultColor, 2))
            {
                int intHeight = this.ClientSize.Height;
                int intWidth = this.ClientSize.Width;

                int intMiddleHeight = intHeight / 2;
                int intMiddleWidth = intWidth / 2;

                Point posTopLeft = new Point(0, 0);
                Point posTopRight = new Point(intWidth, 0);
                Point posBottomLeft = new Point(0, intHeight);
                Point posBottomRight = new Point(intWidth, intHeight);
                Point posMiddle = new Point(intMiddleWidth, intMiddleHeight);
                Point posMiddleTop = new Point(intMiddleWidth, 0);
                Point posMiddleLeft = new Point(0, intMiddleHeight);
                Point posMiddleRight = new Point(intWidth, intMiddleHeight);
                Point posMiddleBottom = new Point(intMiddleWidth, intHeight);

                int defaultStep = randomColor.Next(3, 10);

                int b1;
                for (b1 = 0; b1 <= intMiddleWidth; b1 += defaultStep)
                {
                    g.DrawLine(defaultPen, posTopLeft.X + b1, posTopLeft.Y, posMiddle.X - b1, posMiddle.Y);
                    g.DrawLine(defaultPen, posTopRight.X - b1, posTopRight.Y, posMiddle.X + b1, posMiddle.Y);
                    g.DrawLine(defaultPen, posMiddle.X - b1, posMiddle.Y, posBottomLeft.X + b1, posBottomLeft.Y);
                    g.DrawLine(defaultPen, posMiddle.X + b1, posMiddle.Y, posBottomRight.X - b1, posBottomRight.Y);
                }

                int b2;
                for (b2 = 0; b2 <= intMiddleHeight; b2 += defaultStep)
                {
                    g.DrawLine(defaultPen, posMiddleTop.X, posMiddleTop.Y + b2, posMiddleLeft.X, posMiddleLeft.Y - b2);
                    g.DrawLine(defaultPen, posMiddleTop.X, posMiddleTop.Y + b2, posMiddleRight.X, posMiddleRight.Y - b2);
                    g.DrawLine(defaultPen, posMiddleRight.X, posMiddleRight.Y + b2, posMiddleBottom.X, posMiddleBottom.Y - b2);
                    g.DrawLine(defaultPen, posMiddleLeft.X, posMiddleLeft.Y + b2, posMiddleBottom.X, posMiddleBottom.Y - b2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
private void TmrStep_Tick(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Refresh();
}
```

This will force the repaint of the form. I assume you have the form `.Paint` event assigned to `frmMain_OnPaint()` already.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/132749269